# Obj-C... "Incompatible types in initialization" error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, quartz-2d

My code:

```
CGPoint *tp_1 = CGPointMake(160, 240);
```

gives an "Incompatible types in initialization" error... why is this??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CGPointMake` returns a struct, not a pointer to a struct. So the correct code is:

```
CGPoint tp_1 = CGPointMake(160, 240);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CGPointMake isn't returning a pointer.